# Download File without giving Folder Name

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my project , i have a download button in jqgrid. When I click this button the appropriate file must be downloaded, but here is my problem; all these files come from different folders, so I cannot set a folder name in mappath. I saw different code for downloading, but in every case there has to be a folder name.
   I have gound one solution for this; to bind the folder name & file name in a grid ,but there is a huge amount of data and I cannot change the database.

My question is: how can I download a file without a giving folder name?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) - What are you trying to achieve? Is this folder to download to or to download from? if its the former, thats normally the users decision, if its the latter, why don't you have the folder?

Comment: There must be some parameters in your grid which decides while file to be downloaded. Send those parameters and evaluate which file on the server side (in controller) and send back the file as fileResult. I hope am getting the right context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

> but here my problem is all these files come different folders, so i
>   cannot give folder name in mappath

you can't download a file without knowing the virtual or absolute path. In your case, you want to download a file, but certainly (your code)doesn't know where it resides. more accurately, your code doesn't have a clue to provide the path of the file.

You should be able to provide a mechanism to down the file(be it keeping the file path in a DB table or a mapping of user to folder), you wont get a generic solution to your issue.